# Passing parameters to Task.Factory.StartNew in .NET

Tags: c#, task

I am working on a small utility that will scan a FTP folder that has a folder for each printer on our network. Within each printer folder, there will be files that needs printing.

So, here's the test code I have so far:

```
namespace PrintTest
{
    class Program
    {
        const string ftpDir = @"C:\Users\Latheesan\Desktop\FTP";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartScan();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void StartScan()
        {
            // Scan ftp dir
            var printerDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(ftpDir);

            // Proceed if any printer dirs were found
            if (printerDirs.Length > 0)
            {
                // Init task list
                Task[] scanPrinterTasks = new Task[printerDirs.Length];

                // Iterate through each found printer dir
                for (int i = 0; i < printerDirs.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Configure printer tasks
                    var printerName = printerDirs[i];
                    printerDirs[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                        ScanPrinterDir(printerName));
                }

                // Wait for all tasks to finish
                Task.WaitAll(scanPrinterTasks);
            }
        }

        static void ScanPrinterDir(string printerName)
        {
            // todo
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0029  Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to
>   'string'  PrintTest   C:\Users\Latheesan\Desktop\PrintTest\PrintTest\Program.cs   34

How do you pass parameters to a method invoked by `Task.Factory.StartNew` ?

Comment: Your problem is that `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns a Task, but you're then assigning this to `printerDirs` which is a string array - did you mean to add the returned task to `scanPrinterTasks`?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong in passing parameters here however the return type of [Task.Factory.StartNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) is task not a string which is why you are getting compile time error.

I think you need

```
       scanPrinterTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                    ScanPrinterDir(printerName));
```

instead of

```
      printerDirs[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                    ScanPrinterDir(printerName));
```